# Is talking without moving facial muscles or lips a type of dialect or a physiological problem?

Tags: pronunciation

I have met two people who strikingly speak this way in SW Virginia, my adopted home. It is astounding to watch them speak without using any facial (including lip) muscles, but in one case I could not understand a word. This is not the wealthy lockjaw posh affected speech, but a mumbling way of speaking with a southern accent. I am curious if this is just another fascinating Appalachian dialect or if they are suffering from a physiological condition.

Comment: Hi Anne, and Welcome to English Language and Usage. While very interesting, I am not quite sure if this is on-topic for us. However, I have a question for you. Is it possible that these 2 people are ex-convicts? I have known ex-cons who developed this way of speaking so that they may appear quiet in groups, but talk to those around them.

Comment: If you can do it clearly enough, it can become an occupation (ventriloquist)....  But I think this question doesn't really belong here on ELU, since it's not about English *per se*; it's probably better for either Linguistics or Health.

Comment: probably better for linguistics?

Comment: Probably not physiological.  Many people in the lower socioeconomic strata also speak with limited pitch variation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about English language and usage, but physiological conditions and or body language.